# What does [5, +3] mean on armor and weapons in angband?

Tags: angband

I don't understand how the bonus works on armor and really weapons. I can't seem to find it in the help docs either. Can someone tell me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not a specialist with Angband but I think I found what you're looking for on this [forum](http://angband.oook.cz/forum/showthread.php?t=3346) :

> For armor first two in parenthesis are to_hit and to_dam bonuses (can be disenchanted, but not repaired), second in brackets is armor base value (can't be changed) and bonus (acid can damage this to negative value up to same as base, disenchantment can bring any positive value to zero here), third is power value pval: stealth, searching, stats, speed that sort of things (can't be changed).
>
> Example: Gauntlets of power (+2,+3) [2,+5] (+3)
>
> For weapons it is: parenthesis: weapon dice (like armor base value), weapon to_hit and to_dam bonuses (like AC bonus in armors), Brackets: AC-bonus (like to_hit and to_dam in armors), parenthesis: pval
>
> Example: Katana (Holy Avenger) (3d5) (+10,+15) [+5] (+3)